# Entity Framework - Inheritance

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I am just starting with Entity Framework and have the following problem:

I have a *Site* entity which contains a navigation property *Paragraphs*.

I have multiple entities (i.e. *ImageParagraph*, *LinkListParagraph*) that should be inherited form *Paragraph*.

I would like to query for a *Site* object and access its *Paragraphs* and work with them depending on their concrete type (i.e. *ImageParagraph*, *LinkListParagraph*).

It would work with a Table Per Hierarchy approach (with conditions), but then i would end up in a very dirty solution. Querying for the concrete type based on the Paragraph ID would work, but I hope there is a way better solution.

I want to query for a *Site* and show some Site specific data and the data in the Paragraphs (*ImageParagraph*, *LinkListParagraph*). I do not know how to set up the mapping in a way that it is possible to retrieve *ImageParagraph*, *LinkListParagraph* objects directly over the *Paragraphs* navigation property.

How would you solve this problem?

ER-diagram: http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/46/69863714ks0.jpg

[alt text http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/46/69863714ks0.jpg](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/46/69863714ks0.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with them *based* on their concrete type - that sounds like a case for polymorphism... can you (in a partial class) add a few methods?

```
partial class Paragraph {
    public abstract void Foo();
}
partial class ImageParagraph {
    public override void Foo() {/*code*/}
}
partial class LinkListParagraph {
    public override void Foo() {/*code*/}
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to filter the set, you can use the `OfType` extension method - i.e.

```
foreach(var imgPara in obj.Paragraphs.OfType<ImageParagraph>())
{ ... }
```

Perhaps you could add properties for the above too (in the parent object) - i.e.

```
partial class Site {
    public IQueryable<ImageParagraph> ImageParagraphs
    { get {return Paragraphs.OfType<ImageParagraph>(); }}

    public IQueryable<LinkListParagraph> LinkListParagraphs
    { get {return Paragraphs.OfType<LinkListParagraph>(); }}
}
```

Comment: Thanks.My question was unclear.I want to do: 
var site =context.Site.Include("Paragraphs").Where(c => c.SiteID == 1).First(); 
foreach(var paragraph in site.Paragraphs) { do something }; 
My problem is that I do not know the mapping in the EDM.(like with Table per Hierarchy with conditions)